# Text Plot in R: Is there a way to do a text heat map?

Tags: r, text, heatmap

I have a text document and want to make a heat map out of it, color coding the words according to a numeric value assigned to each word.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

The data frame would be set up like:

```
phrase   value
The      1
black    9
dog      8
jumped   4
quickly  5
when     2
the      1
car      7
started, 8
but...   1
```

Comment: Heatmaps visualize relationships. It looks like you only have univariate data here. What did you envision being the two axis of the heatmap?

Comment: Oh, i should clarify.  What I want as the final output is all of the text put back together as a document.  It will be in paragraph form with the different words/phrases being color coded based on the value.  I get that it's not really a "map" but couldn't think of a better word.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like this:

```
 psych::read.clipboard(header=FALSE)
 head(data)

          X.value X.phrase
 The           1      The
 black         9    black
 dog           8      dog
 jumped        4   jumped
 quickly       5  quickly
 when          2     when

 ggplot(data=data) + geom_text(aes(x=factor(X.phrase), y=X.value, colour=X.value, label=X.phrase))
```

i know it's not too pretty but i think it is a starting point... if you had a second covariate to print along the axis it would be better

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The part I forgot to mention was that I'll need to return it to paragraph form.  The wordcloud package does something similar -- with the colors -- but I don't need the wordcloud, I need it put back together as a paragraph.

Comment: you mean you basically want the same text but with colored words?

Answer (score 2):

```
data<-structure(list(words = c("The", "black", "dog", "jumped", "quickly", 
"when", "the", "car", "started,", "but..."), cols = c(1, 9, 8, 
4, 5, 2, 1, 7, 8, 1)), .Names = c("words", "cols"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

plot(0,0,type='n')
widths <- strwidth(data[,1])
spaces <- rep(strwidth(" "), length(widths)-1)
middle <- mean(par("usr")[1:2])
total <- sum(widths) + sum(spaces)
start <- c(0,cumsum(widths[-length(widths)] + spaces))
total <- sum(widths) + sum(spaces)
start <- start + middle - total/2
pos<-cbind(start,1)
colors<-rainbow(9)

text(pos,data[,1],col=colors[data[,2]],adj=0)
```

[image]

I stole code from Duncan Murdoch linked from here:
http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/multicolor-text-in-r.html

Comment: Yes, between this and Seb's suggestion below, I think we have a solution.  Thanks!